# Laravel: How to sync pivot data with checkboxes

Tags: laravel, view, synchronization, pivot

I have 2 tables: jewels and materials and a pivot table jewel_material with an extra price field.
What I would like to achieve is that the administrator can choose by checkboxes in what materials a jewel will be performed.
For the chosen materials a price must be given.
Making work the checkboxes for the materials was no problem. The additional price field is...
I suppose that I have to put associative input fields in the form with the material_id and the price, but I really don't know how to do it...

Comment: What have you tried, and what obstacles have you encountered? We can help answer specific programming questions. By the way, your entire question lacks a single "?".

Comment: It's the first time I use a forum to ask a question...How can I make an array of two input fields of a form? In the form has a foreach loop that links to a pivot table with extra data. It consists of a checkbox for the id and another field with the extra data (price). How can I put them in an array? Is there a way of grouping them in the form? When I want to sync them, laravel needs an array... The whole form works, also the syncing of the id's in the pivot. It's the additional data I'm really struggling with... Any idea? It would make me sooo happy.